# Is there a way to pass a pointer to a variable without defining it prior based on function prototype requiring a pointer as one if its parameters?

Tags: c, pointers, parameter-passing

I was having issues with `recv()` where I would always get a return of -1, despite there being bytes to read. My problem was that I was calling it like that:

```
ret = recvfrom(socket, &result, 10, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (socklen_t)(sizeof(addr)));
```

While the last parameter was actually a requirement for an address of variable which holds thie size as such. Correct call was as such:

```
socklen_t recsize = sizeof(addr);
ret = recvfrom(socket, &result, 10, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &recsize);
```

Is there a way to pass a pointer to a function requiring a pointer all in one line without having to create a new variable and passing an address of that variable?

Comment: Please choose either C or C++. They are different languages.

Comment: Well, no.   A variable must exist before its address can be obtained.

Comment: @Peter: Well, yes. What the function requires to be passed is not a “variable” but the address of an object, and C provides temporary objects in the form of compound literals.

Comment: Be mindful that `recvfrom` takes a pointer because it sometimes returns information in the pointed-to object. You need that information to handle all potential results of `recvfrom`. If you are not writing code to handle all cases, now is a good time to start developing the discipline to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### C

Use a *compound literal*.

```c
ret = recvfrom(..., &(socklen_t){sizeof(addr)});
```

The object created by a such literal has automatic storage duration (will be destroyed, roughly, when control reaches the next `}`).

#### C++

Write a function that returns the address of an rvalue:

```cpp
template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] T *address_of_rvalue(T &&ref)
{
    return &ref;
}
```

Use it like this:

```cpp
ret = recvfrom(..., address_of_rvalue(socklen_t(sizeof(addr)));
```

The temporary created in this expression will be destroyed at the end of full-expression (roughly, when control reaches the `;`).

Comment: I think' I've seen this notation before somewhere, now I know that it is called compound literal. Thank you!